# How to find Wifi Direct Discovery is finished in android

Tags: android, wifi, wifi-direct

I am developing application using Wifi Direct API in android. I have to discover WiFi p2p devices continuously in the background but i am not able to detect WiFi discovery is finished. Once i able to detect discovery finished, I would start discovery again.

Please Help me to resolve this.Thanks in advance.

```
wifiP2PManager.discoverPeers(wifiP2PChannel, new 
WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {

            Log.i(TAG, "Discovery Started");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int i) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Discovery Failed");

        }
    });
```

I get discovery is start or not in action listner. I but i don't get discovery finished callback.

Comment: Please share the code you already got. The only thing i could point out so far is that the `WifiP2pManager.ActionListener` has two methods, so in success or error case your listener should be called, notifying you that the framework is done discovering services.

Comment: @ Capricorn, I have shared my code. As you have mentioned that there is success and failure methods but it is only responsible to detect whether discovery is start or not. but I want to know for discovery is finished.